# Create React app with Create-React-App fails with ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...er":"^2.0.0","eslint"'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I used the following command to create a React application using Create-React-App tool:

```sh
C:\Users\Valdo\Desktop\Test\React>npx create-react-app my-app
```

But I encountered an error, here is my terminal log:

```sh
Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Valdo\Desktop\Test\React\my-app.

Installing packages.
This might take a couple of minutes.

Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...fdd1679ff","tarball":'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! C:\Users\Valdo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-04-23T16_44_10_449Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from C:\Users\Valdo\Desktop\Test\React
```

Comment: try running `npm cache clean` and then try to create the app again.

Comment: please include your `package.json` file. seems its invalid and the problem might be there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `npm cache clean --force` first and then run your command again, this might solve your problem.

This will delete all data from the cache folder that may be responsible for your error.

Comment: it's still doing it after deleting all the data from cache...help pls i'm getting stressed out and considering moving to vue

Comment: Do you also delete the generated project after it fails?